# I need a listener to see if my notifications table (node) has changed for real time data checking

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

Firebase - I need a listener to see if my notifications table (node) has changed for real time data checking.

I'm using angular2 with typescript and firebase for my project.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Otherwise this question is likely to get closed, due asking for a tutorial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
export class AppComponent {
  items:Array<string>;

  constructor() {
    var firebaseURL = "https://something.firebaseio.com/somethingelse";
    var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL);

    myFirebaseRef.on('child_added', (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) => {
      childSnapshot.forEach((records) => {
        this.items = itemsarr.push(records.val());
      });
      console.log(itemsarr)
    });
    console.log(itemsarr);
  }
}
```

Be careful to instantiate the `Firebase` object within a component to make Angular2 aware of changes of `items`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

**This is my current code but its not firing when the notification is added to the table:**

```
waitingForNotificationChanges = (): void => {
    this.refNotifications.on('child_added', (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) => {          
        console.log("Notification table changed");
        this.getNumberOfNotificationsByUid();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry, I will try now

Comment: I've added my current code above from what you gave me. For some reason it didnt fire

Comment: How and when do you call the `waitingForNotificationChanges` method?

Comment: I never call it. Do I need to move it to a constructor?

Comment: That's a problem ;-) Because this method is responsible to register your callback on Firebase. You should call it from the contructor for example: `constructor() { (...) this.waitingForNotificationChanges(); }`

Comment: I think that you have a lot of things in Frebase ;-) Do you want to get all because you can limit the number of elements retrieved with `limitToLast`...

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177288/angular2-firebase-realtime-updating-not-working/35177583#35177583

Comment: Works fine now. I used limit to:  this.refNotifications.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) => {});