# How to declare an observable on angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

How can i declare an observable and how to add data to it in angular2 ?
I have 5 hours trying to figure out how to do it.

I tryed this

```
this.products : Observable<array>;
var object = {"item":item};
this.products.subscribe(object)
```

everything i tryed throws me an error

I want to use it because i have an array of objects that is changing frequently and in the template the ngFor is not changing the values.
Any help?

http://pastebin.com/1cFXJHHk
Here is what i try to do

Comment: I suggest providing a plnkr that demonstrates the issue.  It's not clear otherwise, what the issue may be.

Comment: i provided a pastebin .. i`m sure when you will see it you will get the right answer.

Comment: Based on your pastebin, I don't think you need to use Observables at all (aside from Http).  You can probably do everything you need to using `@Input` bindings alone (maybe an `@Output` binding too). Its still not clear to me how or why you want to use Observables.

Comment: If i use an array the template is not changing when i change the values of the array and as i saw on the internet i should use observables . am i wrong ?

Comment: Updates to array bindings should happen automatically by default. If its not updating, it could be something with your code. That shouldn't be a reason to use observables instead.

Comment: it seems that what happends in the startInterval stays in the startinterval .. have no idea on how to modify the this.products array from the startInterval function.Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@pixelbits provided a great answer describing the way to use raw observables.

But I think you misunderstood what observables and reactive programming are. You could have a look at this great introduction to start:

- The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing - https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

The `subscribe` method of obersables allows to register callbacks for notifications:

- The first parameter for the callback regarding events
- The second one for the callback regarding errors
- The last one for the completion

Of course you can leverage events to add an element in a list but I'm not sure that it's your use case:

```
var someList = [];
let observable = (...)
observable.subscribe(data => {
  someList.push(data);
});
```

This is particularly useful for event-based tools / technologies like WebSockets, Firebase, ... The observable above would be linked on them. This answer could give you more details on how to implement this with Firebase:

- [I need a listener to see if my notifications table (node) has changed for real time data checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200460/i-need-a-listener-to-see-if-my-notifications-table-node-has-changed-for-real-t/35200494#35200494)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create an Observable (cold), you can use the create method:

```
myEvent:Rx.Observable<{item:Item}>;
myObserver: Rx.Observer<{item:Item}>;
constructor() {
    this.myEvent = Rx.Observable.create(o=>this.myObserver = o);
}
someEvent() {
    // do something
    var $event = {item:new Item()};

    // emit the event object when something interesting happens
    if(this.myObserver)
        this.myObserver.emit($event);
}
```

Comment: this seems really complicated . it works to ngFor  the observable that is changing frequently?

Comment: this is why i need it

Comment: I guess whether or not to use an Observable depends on your use case. You can get by with using EventEmitters inside of a component, which if I recall is similar to a ReplaySubject.