# How to create an observable method that itself calls an HTTP method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a service that updates a record.  The normal httpPut call works fine, but I want to subscribe to the save method and wait for the the save method to finish, just like the http call does.

54844328 - this post seem really close to what I needed, but obviously I have not done this correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
save(href, recordModel): Observable<boolean> {
    let returnValue = true;
    return new Observable((observer ) => {
      this.dataService.httpPut(href, recordModel).subscribe(resp => {
          returnValue = true;
        },
        (resp) => {
          this.statusError('put()');
          returnValue = false;
        });
      this.logger.info('save', returnValue);
      observer.next(returnValue);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }


this.dynamicListsService.save(this.editModel._links.self.href, this.editModel).subscribe(resp => {
            if (resp) {
              this.dynamicListsData = this.dynamicListsService.getAll();
              this.setAppMessage(appMessages.recordSaved);
              this.logger.debug("APP GOOD");
            } else {
              this.logger.debug("APP BAD");
              super.dialogError();
            }
          });
```

Comment: 54844328 ? can you add the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667891/how-to-create-an-observable-within-an-observable-in-angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Observable` constructor is an antipattern, in case you want to create an observable from existing observable, like you do in the question. It is better to use correct operators, which we have plenty in rxjs. This code should behave exacly the same like in the question, but with fixed `logger.info`, because it will be executed at the correct moment

```
save(href, recordModel): Observable<boolean> {
   let returnValue: boolean;
   this.dataService.httpPut(href, recordModel).pipe(
     map(() => returnValue = true),
     catchError(() => {
       this.statusError('put()');
       return of(returnValue = false);
     }),
     finalize(() => this.logger.info('save', returnValue)) 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `observer.next()` inside of the subscribe. Right now, your `observer` is going to get called before your httppost call has a chance to finish because it is happening outside of its subscription.

To go along with that, you can then add the error handler to the subscribe and make sure to fire the `observer.error()` call as well to bubble up that error to whatever is using this function.