# Ionic 2 - Subscribe not working until interacting with the page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a facebook login which uses the facebook connect 4 plugin along with firebase. the data gets passed to a inter component service which then relays it back to the component via a subscribe.. however the data doesnt display until you interact with the UI.. anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: can you add the code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have the answer here : [angular2 firebase realtime updating not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177288/angular2-firebase-realtime-updating-not-working)

Applications from outside angular2 does not trigger a digest cycle. Wich means you can trigger it with NgZone or it gets done when you manipulate the UI.